# Access token appendix http header

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, http-headers, authorization

I’m using a 3rd party identity provider that is a little restrictive with adding claims to the token.

As an alternative, I’m sending a token appendix together with that 3rd party token, but the appendix is in a custom http header (not the authZ header). The token appendix contains everything I wish the 3rd party token could contain. It also has a signature like a JWT and it takes the entire 3rd party token as well as itself into account when creating this signature. Therefore, it is bound to a particular 3rd party token.

Is that a well known solution (that maybe even has a special name)? Did I just invent something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your case should be something like **Custom Authorization Scheme**.

But there is one thing you need to pay attention to:

> A custom Authorization scheme can be unexpected and unsupported by
> some clients and leads to custom code anyway.
> Say clients, say
> libraries, frameworks, reverse proxies. A custom header can be
> rejected or ignored. In the worse of the cases, it can also collide.
> Collisions can be problematic, but all other issues are likely to be
> solved by tackling configurations.

As for choosing Authorization or custom header, in my opinion, technically, both take me almost the same work and time to implement, with a slight difference. I had more room for design when I implemented custom headers. However, more room for design also meant more chances to overcomplicate things or reinvent the wheel.

Hope this can help you.